# Trying to get any response when connecting from Android to my web service (SOAP 1.1)

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

This is my only class where i get connected to my web service :

```
    public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

 private static final String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/getme/TSM/LogOn";
 private static final String METHOD_NAME="LogOn";
 private static final String NAMESPACE="http://tempuri.org/getme/TSM/";
 private static final String URL="http://theking/eget/WebService/WSAuth.asmx";

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        Request.addProperty("strUsername", "Test");
        Request.addProperty("strPassword", "Test123");
        Request.addProperty("strMessage", "hello");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        AndroidHttpTransport aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        try
        {
         aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
         SoapObject response = (SoapObject)soapEnvelope.getResponse();
            String LogonResult =  response.getProperty(0).toString();
            String MessageResult =  response.getProperty(1).toString();
         tv.setText("Status : " + LogonResult + " Message: " + MessageResult);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } }
```

I think it breaks before the TRY tag.. all i get on the virtual screen is : false.
Any solutions.. i don't know where is the problem ?

The following is a sample SOAP request and response.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <LogOn xmlns="http://tempuri.org/getme/TSM">
      <strUsername>string</strUsername>
      <strPassword>string</strPassword>
      <strMessage>string</strMessage>
    </LogOn>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <LogOnResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/getme/TSM">
      <LogOnResult>int</LogOnResult>
      <strMessage>string</strMessage>
    </LogOnResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I've played a little with Toast's and i saw that it's going in the TRY method, but it falls right after the first line : aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope); and it's going in the catch.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem I just add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Thats it :)

Answer (score 0):

make sure that in your android application config file you have allowed remote access.

Also try pasting the URL into a browser and see whether it is correct.

Also set a breakpoint or log in a file to determine whether the service will get invoked.

Comment: 1) i got this in my manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> - 2) the URL is working when i paste in browser - 3) i get this error msg: java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: gavgamela:80. I've red some topics around for the same problem, it says to recreate the emulator but still nothing. Any other solution ?

Comment: Could you please share some details on how did you solve the problem?

Comment: @ Rijndael:it will be useful to all SO users if u post your solution.